# Migrating code from AFNetworking 2 to 3

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I have the following AFNetworking 2 code (from a library) that I am trying to migrate to AFNetworking 3 but I can't understand how to data tasks instead of NSOperations. Any help would be appreciated:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                           path:messagePath
                                     parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *_operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                      if (success) {
                                                                          success(responseObject);
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *_operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                      NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                                      if (failure) {
                                                                          failure(error);
                                                                      }
                                                                  }];
```

Comment: What do you want to say?

Comment: Follow this link. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: @user1686342 Did you find a solution for this. I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Do like following:

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[manager GET:@"Enter_your_URL_here" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} 
failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
];
```

Comment: Assigning `manager.responseSerializer` twice looks sub-optimal.